# Event publishing to Amazon SNS destination

Tags: amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I am getting account level notifications from Amazon SNS. But I am not getting event publishing notifications.

I set up configuration set and gave sns destinations as endpoints. In account level notifications we get bounces, complaints and delivery notifications. But I want open and click tracking for emails. So I created event publishing events. I am giving configuration set name while I am sending email.

Do we need to set sender email as AWS account email or we can any verified email?

Is there any way troubleshoot that configuration set is passing or not?

Comment: Did you apply for a limit increase to get out of the sandbox phase? All SNS starts in a sandbox mode and you can't use other senders until you get out of that. Most of the SNS errors I have would be seen on the caller side, or whatever is trying to create the notification

Comment: Yes, We are out of sandbox phase. I am getting account level sns notifications. Not getting via configuration set